# How to load huge data around 5 Million Data using laravel and data table? Also i have an issue with Pagination in Serer Side Processing

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

How to load huge data around 5 Million Data  using laravel and data table? Also i have an issue with Pagination in Serer Side Processing

Comment: How is your loading time??

Comment: The only way I can think of loading that data, is to paginate them. This way you don't need to worry about the huge amount of data. because you always returning part of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables I am working with 50m data but i don't use yajra's datatable. If you want to build your codes:

Datatable Method

```
public function indexDataTable ( Request $request )
        {
            $aColumns    = [
                'checkbox',
                'id',
                'title',
                'description',
                'created_at',
                'options',
            ];

            $limit       = $request->input ( 'length' );
            $start       = $request->input ( 'start' );
            $orderColumn = "id";
            $dir         = $request->input ( 'order.0.dir' ) ?? 'desc';

            $posts = null;

            //For starting query
            $posts = Post::where ( 'id', '>', 0 );

            $totalData = $posts->count ();


            if ( ! empty( $request->input ( 'columns.1.search.value' ) ) )
            {
                $postId = $request->input ( 'columns.1.search.value' );

                $posts = $posts->where ( 'id', $postId );
            }

            //other filters

            if ( $limit == -1 )
                $limit = 100000;

            $totalFiltered = $posts->count ();

            $posts = $posts->offset ( $start )
                ->limit ( $limit );

            $requestAll = $request->all();

            if (isset($requestAll['order'][0]['column']))
            {
                $orderColumn = $aColumns[$requestAll['order'][0]['column']];
            }

            $posts = $posts->orderBy ( $orderColumn, $dir );

            $posts = $posts->get();

            $data = [];
            if ( ! empty( $posts ) )
            {
                foreach ( $posts as $post )
                {
                    $edit = route ( 'posts.edit', $post->id );

                    $nestedData['checkbox']                 = "<div class=\"custom-control custom-checkbox\"><input type=\"checkbox\" id='order_ids{$post->id}' name='post_ids[]' value='{$post->id}' class=\"custom-control-input order-checkbox\"><label class=\"custom-control-label\" for=\"order_ids{$post->id}\"></label></div>";
                    $nestedData['id']                       = $post->id;
                    $nestedData['title']                    = $post->title;
                    $nestedData['description']              = $post->description;
                    $nestedData['created_at']               = $post->created_at->format ( "Y-m-d H:i:s");
                    $nestedData['options']                  = "<a href='{$edit}'><i class='mdi mdi-pencil font-16'></i></a>";
                    $data[]                                 = $nestedData;
                }
            }

            $json_data = [
                "draw"            => intval ( $request->input ( 'draw' ) ),
                "recordsTotal"    => intval ( $totalData ),
                "recordsFiltered" => intval ( $totalFiltered ),
                "data"            => $data
            ];

            echo json_encode ( $json_data );

        }
```

In Route:

```
Route::post ( 'posts/datatable', 'PostController@indexDatatable' )->name ( 'posts.datatable' );
```

In Blade:

```
<form id="datatable_form" target="_blank" method="post" action="#">
    @csrf
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="posts">
        <thead>
            <th scope="col">@lang('posts.index.columns.checkbox')</th>
            <th scope="col">@lang('posts.index.columns.id')</th>
            <th scope="col">@lang('posts.index.columns.title')</th>
            <th scope="col">@lang('posts.index.columns.description')</th>
            <th scope="col">@lang('posts.index.columns.created_at')</th>
            <th scope="col">@lang('posts.index.columns.action')</th>
        </thead>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>
                    <input type="text" data-column="1"
                           class="data-table-search-input-text form-control"
                           style="width: 100%">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input type="text" data-column="2"
                           class="data-table-search-input-text form-control"
                           style="width: 100%">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input type="text" data-column="3"
                           class="data-table-search-input-text form-control"
                           style="width: 100%">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input type="text" data-column="4"
                           class="data-table-search-input-text form-control"
                           style="width: 100%">
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

<script>
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $ ('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr ('content')
        }
    });

    var postsTable = $ ('#posts').dataTable ({
        "ordering": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "{{ route('panel.posts.datatable') }}",
            "dataType": "json",
            "type": "POST"
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "checkbox"},
            {"data": "id"},
            {"data": "title"},
            {"data": "description"},
            {"data": "created_at"},
            {"data": "options"}
        ],
        "order": [[1, "desc"]],
        "language": {
            "processing": "@lang('pagination.datatable.processing')",
            "lengthMenu": "@lang('pagination.datatable.lengthMenu')",
            "zeroRecords": "@lang('pagination.datatable.zeroRecords')",
            "info": "@lang('pagination.datatable.info')",
            "infoEmpty": "@lang('pagination.datatable.infoEmpty')",
            "infoFiltered": "@lang('pagination.datatable.infoFiltered')",
            "paginate": {
                "first": "@lang('pagination.datatable.paginate.first')",
                "previous": "@lang('pagination.datatable.paginate.previous')",
                "next": "@lang('pagination.datatable.paginate.next')",
                "last": "@lang('pagination.datatable.paginate.last')"
            }
        },
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "Hepsi"]],
        stateSave: false,
    });

    $ ('.data-table-search-input-text').on ('keyup change', function () {
        var inputElement = $ (this);

        ojoDelay (function () {

            var i = inputElement.attr ('data-column');
            var v = inputElement.val ();
            postsTable.api ().columns (i).search (v).draw ();
            //usersTable.api ().ajax.reload ();
        }, 1000, this);
    });

</script>

<script>
ojoDelay = (function () {
    var timer = 0;
    return function (callback, ms, that) {
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout (callback.bind (that), ms);
    };
}) ();
</script>
```

Comment: what is the server requirments? we have shared server

Comment: We have an ERP build on PHP- Laravel with 30 Applications in an Single  ERP- with CRM, HRM, Purchase, Sales, Finance, etc...... The data base is single data base with mutli branch ID concept - we need to Fetch data, Export PDF, and data need to fetch using data table / other method--

Comment: Really? i shared codes with you, and ask me what is server reqs? If you don't filter anything doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. My issue is i have many calculated columns in the app and yajra/laravel-datatables is great but doesnt provide sorting on calculated columns. I might have to implement the DataTable server end manually too.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly follow this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKxls7qCZPE

It explains How to fast load Big Data or 1 Million in Laravel using DataTables Server Side Processing in Laravel.

The uniqueness of this solution is that it uses **DB Facade** for example
`DB::table('users')`
other than a Model query builder
`User::all()` which may also take a longer time to load even though you are using server-side processing.

Below is how the code you should use in the controller. You can modify it according to your requirements but this is just startup.

```
$data=  DB::table('users');
return DataTables::queryBuilder($data)->toJson();
```